# Como manter um checkbox "checked" após uma filtragem

Tags: angularjs, html5

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:{components:component} | filter:{classification:class}:true">
     <ul>
          <div class="selected-{{'{{charter.selected}}'}}" ng-hide="post.charters.length <= 0" ng-repeat="charter in post.charters">
               <input type="checkbox" ng-model="charter.selected" ng-change="addSelectedCharters(post, charter)">
                    {{'{{charter}}'}}
          </div>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Quando eu filtro, todos os checkbox que antes estavam marcados, não estão mais. Como posso resolver? Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que crie uma propriedade nos seus itens, que poderia ser:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:{components:component} | filter:{classification:class}:true">
     <ul>
          <div class="selected-{{'{{charter.selected}}'}}" ng-hide="post.charters.length <= 0" ng-repeat="charter in post.charters">
               <input type="checkbox" ng-model="post.selected" ng-change="addSelectedCharters(post, charter)">
                    {{'{{charter}}'}}
          </div>
     </ul>
</div>
```

A diferença está aqui `ng-model="post.selected"`.

Comment: Agradeço sua dica, mas na verdade são os charters que possuem o checkbox cada um e não o post. Cada post contém vários charters. Quero selecionar vários charters, e quando filtrar manter os charters dos outros posts ainda selecionados, mesmo que não apareçam após a filtragem. Deu par entender melhor? Muito obrigado!